# Given the VB.net code, combine multiple queries into 1

Tags: sql, vb.net

Given this code below which returns a first recordset (rs) based on a date range with some values that are then used in the second recordset (rs2) to sum up a cost.  Further explanation is below the code:

```
strSQL = "SELECT job, suffix, isnull(qty_scrapped,0),isnull(qty_released,0), isnull(price,0),co_num FROM vwDashboardsQuality "
strSQL &= "        WHERE trans_date >= '" & dtpStartDate.Value & "' AND trans_date <= '" & dtpEndDate.Value & "' "

rs = conn.Execute(strSQL)

While Not rs.EOF
    strCONUM = Trim("" & rs("co_num").Value)

    strSelectString = "SELECT ISNULL(a_cost,0) FROM jobmatl WHERE job='" & rs("job").Value & "' AND suffix = " & Format(rs("suffix").Value)

     rs2 = conn.Execute(strSelectString)
     While Not rs2.EOF
         dblSumActualMaterialCost = dblSumActualMaterialCost + CDbl(rs2(0).Value)
         rs2.MoveNext()
     End While
     rs2.Close()
     rs2 = Nothing
     rs.MoveNext()
End While
rs.Close()
rs = Nothing
```

I want to combine the queries into a single query so I am not hitting the database through the second recordset (rs2) just to sum up something that I know can be done in a single query.

Any tips would be helpful.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: is this Legacy code?  is that ADO?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're just needing to do an `inner join` on the two queries to get one result set.

See if this works.  If so, you can eliminate the second query and second inner loop.

```
 strSQL = "SELECT d.job, d.suffix, isnull(d.qty_scrapped,0), isnull(d.qty_released,0)," _
 & " isnull(d.price,0), d.co_num, ISNULL(m.a_cost,0)" _
 & " FROM vwDashboardsQuality d" _
 & " INNER JOIN jobmatl m" _
 & " ON d.job = m.job" _
 & " AND d.suffix = m.suffix" _
 & " WHERE trans_date >= '" & dtpStartDate.Value & "'" _
 & " AND trans_date <= '" & dtpEndDate.Value & "'"
```

You can paste this in Management Studio, replacing dates as applicable to check the results.

```
SELECT d.job, d.suffix, isnull(d.qty_scrapped,0), isnull(d.qty_released,0), isnull(d.price,0), d.co_num,
    ISNULL(m.a_cost,0)
FROM vwDashboardsQuality d
    INNER JOIN jobmatl m
    ON d.job = m.job
    AND d.suffix = m.suffix
WHERE trans_date >= '2015-09-29' 
    AND trans_date <= '2015-09-30'
```

Comment: thanks!  worked like a charm ... talk about having a brain freeze

Comment: I won't tell anyone. :)  Glad I could help.

Comment: additionally, you can use the **BETWEEN** statement `trans_data BETWEEN '2015-09-29' AND '2015-09-30'` in the **Where** Clause

Comment: Be careful when using `BETWEEN` clause [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score -1):

From your code I see that you are at the end just running a `SUM` on all values for `jobmatl.a_cost` that fulfill a condition set by the where clause. So why not doing everything on the same query? And you will save yourself all the unnecessary iterations on the result set, you are loosing previous CPU time and resources there.

Also, you are not using all other values on the first query, why getting them on the first place? I removed them from the following query.

```
SELECT  SUM(j.a_cost)
FROM    vwDashboardsQuality vDQ
        INNER JOIN jobmatl j
            ON vDQ.job = j.job
               AND vDQ.suffix = j.suffix
WHERE   vDQ.trans_date >= @startdate
        AND vDQ.trans_date <= @enddate;
```

Comment: actually they are being used, I just didn't include that code.

Comment: My guess is because the OP produced a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and your solution stripped it down too far.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't means that the answer is incorrect, is correct for his purpose of getting one query and even with the needed result without iterating on the code. Nevertheless, thanks